# MariaDB query finding multiple values in a comma separated string

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have a table of Padlocks which (unfortunately) consists of a column with comma-separated data.
Table consists of padlocks with information of types of Locks given padlock has (and whether it's big or small).
Given a key, which can unlock certain types of locks (and size) I want to find which Padlocks I would be able to unlock. A key has also a comma-separated Lock types and a size.

**Padlocks**

| Name | Locks | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | KL, OK, CZ, CZ | Small |
| B | OK, OK | Small |
| C | OK, CZ, KL | Small |
| D | RO, CZ, CZ | Small |
| E | OK, OK, KL, KL | Small |
| F | OK, OK, CZ, KL | Big |

(Input) Key ('KL, OK, OK, CZ, CZ', 'Small') would return

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

Note, that if a Key is able to unlock only one instance of 'KL', it would not unlock Padlock 'E' as it needs double 'KL, KL'. Padlock 'D' cannot be unlocked  as it needs 'RO'. Padlock 'F' cannot be unlocked because it needs a 'Big' Key.

What I would do, if it were some programming language like C#, I'd split Key's input into array ['KL','OK','OK','CZ','CZ'] and for each row I would also split Locks into array and compare both arrays

Pseudocode

```
foreach Lock in Locks
for(i=0;i<UBound(Lock);i++)
 for(j=0;i<UBound(Key);j++)
  If(Lock[i]=Key[j]) Lock[i].Remove Key[j].Remove
```

If at some point Lock is left with 0 values then the Key can open that lock. But that is way over what I can do in MariaDB.
I know of FIND_IN_SET() but that would let me search for one input only, unless there is a way to use it to fit my needs

PS
Select @@version = 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2

PS2
Would normalizing help? I mean, I could create a table Locks which would hold all the lock types and then create a cross reference table for Padlocks<->Locks. Would there be an SQL statement that would let me get what I need?

Comment: What does the query `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2

Comment: Okay, I've edited to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. Please be aware that these are different products, and answers for one are not necessarily useful for the other. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed significantly since then, and we should not think of them as compatible anymore.

Comment: If you are able to move to a newer MariaDB version and change the list to a JSON array, maybe `WHERE `[JSON_ARRAY_INTERSECT(Locks, InputArray) = InputArray](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_array_intersect/) would solve the hard bit of that problem

Comment: @danblack almost; the order may be different, but `json_length(JSON_ARRAY_INTERSECT(Locks, InputArray)) = json_length(InputArray)` works I think?

Comment: 10.3 is no longer supported; highly recommend you upgrade to 10.11 or at least 10.6 (those are the two 10.x long term support releases)

Comment: or = [JSON_NORMALIZE(InputArray)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_normalize/)  maybe. Note `Small`/`Big` is taken out of `InputArray`. Not sure, will be something close. Without the upgrade ^ (well highlighted) I wasn't going to put much effort here. To solve this problem the richer functionality of JSON is one way to because the FIND_IN_SET obviously isn't totally sufficient (and pulling the result and processing "double" locks in application is probably as close as can be acheived).

Comment: I have edited my question with an option of normalizing the db - would that help?

Comment: btw very good minimal test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By normalizing locks to a new table is pretty straight forward:

```
create table paddocks (
pd char(1),
sz enum('Small', 'Big'),
key (sz));
```

```
create table locks (
pd char(1),
lk char(2),
key (pd,lk));
```

```
insert into paddocks values
('A', 'Small'),
('B', 'Small'),
('C', 'Small'),
('D', 'Small'),
('E', 'Small'),
('F', 'Big')
```

```
insert into locks values ('A', 'KL'),('A', 'OK'),('A', 'CZ'),('A', 'CZ'),
('B', 'OK'),('B', 'OK'),
('C', 'OK'),('C', 'CZ'), ('C', 'KL'),
('D', 'RO'),('D', 'CZ'), ('D', 'CZ'),
('E', 'OK'),('E', 'OK'), ('E', 'KL'), ('E', 'KL'),
('F', 'OK'),('F', 'OK'), ('F', 'CZ'), ('F', 'KL');
```

Then create a temporary table for the keys you have:

```
create temporary table ky (
lk char(2),
key (lk));
```

```
insert into ky values
('KL'),('OK'),('CZ'),('OK'),('CZ')
```

This forms part of the intermediary query to work out how many locks of each time for each paddock.

```
select pd, locks.lk, count(locks.lk)
from paddocks
join locks using (pd)
where sz = 'Small'
group by pd, locks.lk
```

| pd | lk | count(locks.lk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | CZ | 2 |
| A | KL | 1 |
| A | OK | 1 |
| B | OK | 2 |
| C | CZ | 1 |
| C | KL | 1 |
| C | OK | 1 |
| D | CZ | 2 |
| D | RO | 1 |
| E | KL | 2 |
| E | OK | 2 |

Compare this to how many keys we have of each type:

```
SELECT pd,
       p.lk,
       p.c,
       count(ky.lk) AS kc
FROM
  (SELECT pd,
          locks.lk AS lk,
          count(locks.lk) AS c
   FROM paddocks
   JOIN locks USING (pd)
   WHERE sz = 'Small'
   GROUP BY pd,
            locks.lk) p
LEFT JOIN ky USING (lk)
GROUP BY pd,
         lk
```

| pd | lk | c | kc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | CZ | 2 | 2 |
| A | KL | 1 | 1 |
| A | OK | 1 | 2 |
| B | OK | 2 | 2 |
| C | CZ | 1 | 2 |
| C | KL | 1 | 1 |
| C | OK | 1 | 2 |
| D | CZ | 2 | 2 |
| D | RO | 1 | 0 |
| E | KL | 2 | 1 |
| E | OK | 2 | 2 |

Now group by `pd` again and select those, for all locks, have more keys than locks. The `count(pd)` is the number of locks. `c <= kc` is a boolean 0 if there is insufficient keys and 1 if there are sufficient keys. For all lock types there should be sufficient keys.

```
SELECT pd
FROM
  (SELECT pd,
          p.lk,
          p.c,
          count(ky.lk) AS kc
   FROM
     (SELECT pd,
             locks.lk AS lk,
             count(locks.lk) AS c
      FROM paddocks
      JOIN locks USING (pd)
      WHERE sz = 'Small'
      GROUP BY pd,
               locks.lk) p
   LEFT JOIN ky USING (lk)
   GROUP BY pd,
            lk) p
GROUP BY pd
HAVING count(pd) = sum(c <= kc)
```

| pd |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xPQN1fUj)

Comment: Wow, amazing. Quite a few commands i did not know. Anyway, normalizing (or at least trying) table atm. Once I am done I will apply this solution

Comment: if you find yourself in a relaxing mode, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928293/mariadb-query-finding-results-that-partially-match-elements-in-table where I have posted an extension to this question